# How to add background image in accordion in mui

Tags: material-ui

Im trying to add an image in accordion Collapsed with CSS but it is not overriding.
`background: url(./image.svg)`

css
`background:url(image.svg)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use expandIcon props in AccordionSummary

Check [this link](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/accordion-summary/#props) of document